# Card payments not available in Adaptive Payments PayPal

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, credit-card, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm using this priject https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-dotnet in sandbox environment. I'm using Delayed Chained Payments and I have upgraded my sandbox account to PRO, however, when normal user is redirected to paypal site to pay https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=AP-7UP78268M6518143U there is no option to pay with a credit/debit cards.

Any experience with this issue?

**EDIT**: Andrew Angell solution is correct. But, if you use Pay method and you specify senderEmail field, you will still not be able to see credit card option, even if you clear browsing data, how Andrew is suggesting. So the correct answer is Andrew's + do not specify senderEmail field in pay request.

Comment: Yes, if you specify a sender email then it assumes you'll be using that PayPal account to pay and will not need a guest checkout option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Payments Pro is completely separate from Adaptive Payments.  You don't need Pro in order to use Adaptive Payments, and adding Pro will do nothing to enhance your Adaptive Payments options.

Adaptive Payments itself does provide a Guest Checkout experience, but this still happens on the PayPal pages and is cookie dependent, so if your browser has been used to sign in to a PayPal account at any time the system will assume you will be again and won't show the credit card option as prominently as it would otherwise.

Try clearing your cookies/cache in your browser, or just loading up a fresh browser that you don't normally use and try there.  You should notice a difference.

Again, though, if you want to process credit cards directly on your site without any redirect through PayPal, that's what Payments Pro is for, but you can't do a chained payment like that.